# WP User Query get all authors with last name starting with specific letter

Tags: wp-query, users, sql, wp-user-query

I need to program a page to which I pass an initial through the url and it will show all author users whose last name starts with that letter. I would like to do this via WP User Query so that I can easily loop over the results

Right now I have this:

```
<?php $letter = $_GET['p'] ?>
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT umfirst.meta_value AS first_name, umlast.meta_value AS last_name
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta umfirst, $wpdb->usermeta umlast, $wpdb->users user
          WHERE umlast.meta_key = 'last_name'
          AND umfirst.meta_key = 'first_name'
          AND umfirst.user_id = umlast.user_id
          AND user.id = umfirst.user_id
          AND umlast.meta_value LIKE '".$letter."%'";

  $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // Do stuff with the results
  }
?>
```

However I would prefer to user WP Query since it's easier to add other constraints, but I can't get this one to work with WP Query `umlast.meta_value LIKE '".$letter."%'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use the value for the `LIKE` comparison as you've mentioned. The generated `SQL` will look something along the lines of:

```
AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%B%'
```

which means that the query is set to look for every occurrence of letter `B` in our case. Of course this is not what you want, what you would need is something like this:

```
AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE 'B%'
```

so that the search will be done only **starting with** the `B` letter.

The good news is that you can still achieve what you need but with the cost of looking a bit like a hack. :)

The `WP_User_Query`:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'      => 'last_name',
    'meta_value'    => 'B########', // The '########' sequence acts sort of like an unique identifier
    'meta_compare'  => 'LIKE',
);

$wt_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

And in `functions.php` we hook to the `get_meta_sql` filter and alter the `WHERE` clause:

```
function wt_custom_meta_sql( $sql ) {
    /* 
        Search for that funky so called unique identifier
        that we used to initialize our `WP_User_Query' object    
    */
    $uid = '########';
    preg_match( "/'(%[^']+{$uid}%)'/", $sql['where'], $matches );

    if ( ! empty( $matches ) ) {
        /* 
            We've found it and now we get rid of the
            extra '%' character as well as our identifier               
        */
        $val = str_replace( "{$uid}%", "%", ltrim( $matches[1], '%' ) );
        $sql['where'] = str_replace( $matches[0], "'{$val}'", $sql['where'] );
    }

    return $sql;
}
add_filter( 'get_meta_sql' , 'wt_custom_meta_sql', 40 );
```

Comment: @JuanFuentes Also, never build your queries like you did with data (your `$letter` variable) taken directly from input without any filtering. This is the premise of an [`SQL` injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).